# c++ inheritance/multi-inheritance ambiguous call

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Beginner C++ question:

I have a class Person that has protected variables FirstName and LastName:

```
class Person
{
protected:
    int Id;
    std::string FirstName;
    std::string LastName;

public:
    Person();
    Person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName);
    ~Person();
    std::string GetPersonInfo() const;
    std::string GetFirstName() const;
    std::string GetLastName() const;
};

inline std::string Person::GetPersonInfo() const {
    return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}

inline std::string Person::GetFirstName() const {
    return FirstName;
}

inline std::string Person::GetLastName() const {
    return LastName;
}
```

I have a Teacher class that inherits from Person (and an Adult Class)

```
class Teacher :
    public Person, public Adult
{
private:
    int ClassroomID;
public:
    Teacher() = default;
    ~Teacher() = default;
    Teacher(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber,
        std::vector<Address> teacherAddress, int classroomID);

};
```

In my main() I have the following:

```
vector<Teacher> teachers = TeacherRepository.RetrieveTeachers();
            for (Teacher teacher : teachers) {
                cout << teacher.GetFirstName(); }
```

When I start to type "teacher." I see "GetFirstName" appear as an option, however; it is throws a compiler error that "Teacher::GetFirstName is ambiguous"

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: Definition for Adult

```
class Adult :
    public Person
{
protected:
    std::string Email;
    std::string PhoneNumber;
    std::vector<Address> address;
public:
    Adult() = default;
    ~Adult() = default;
    Adult(std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber, std::vector<Address> address);
    Adult(std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber);

};
```

Comment: Where's your definition for `Adult`?

Comment: I added the definition for Adult.  I did not have a GetFirstName in it's definition.

Comment: Why inherit `Teacher` from `Person` and `Adult` when `Adult` is already a `Person`?

Comment: @FredLarson - Good question.  I did that because my constructor for a Teacher is "Teacher::Teacher(variables)  : Person(firstName, lastName), Adult(other variables)".  I guess based off your comment that I can omit that second inheritance and just pass everything to Adult

Comment: Do you want your `Adult` and `Teacher` have `Firstname` and `Lastname` and `Id`? If so, you should initialize the base class objects in your derived classes.

Comment: @hiimdaosui - Yes.  And thanks for mentioning that, I did it with Teacher but not Adult

Comment: Are you really sure inheritance is the right way to model your requirements? How about allowing every `Person` to have any number of roles, like teacher, with any necessary ancillary data?

Comment: @Deduplicator- I could go that route, sure.  Really this is just a pet project of mine that was originally started in C# and now I have to learn C++ so I'm re-writing it to learn the basics of C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect hierarchy. Teacher inherit from Person and Adult at the same time and Adult inherit Person too. What do you want compiler call when you write Teacher::GetFirstName? Maybe Person::GetFirstName or Adult::Person::GetFirstName. Moreover you will have two exemplars of Person's variables.

**Decisions:**

1. virtual inheritance:

   `class Adult : virtual public Person {...};
    class Teacher : virtual public Person, public Adult {...};`

more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance)

2. teacher's basic class must be Adult only:

   `class Teacher : public Adult {...};`

As **bad** option: you can to indicate explicit which certainly method you want to call:

```
`Teacher t = ...;
t.Adult::GetFirstName();`
```

Bonus: Don't pass arguments by value, in your case will be better pass arguments as constant reference.

```
`Person(const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName);`
```

Instead

```
 `Person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName);`
```

Comment: A `std::string_view` by value generally trumps a `std::string` by constant reference.

Comment: @Deduplicator, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your previous design. The direct issue that causes the compilation error is that your `Teacher` is inherited from both `Adult` and `Person` class. Since `Adult` is also a subclass of `Person`, both of those classes have `GetLastName()` method, so the compiler cannot tell which one to call.

More importantly, you should manage your hierarchy in a more correct and clear way. Semantically, an adult should also be a person and a teacher is supposed to be an adult. So why not just inherit `Teacher` from `Adult` only and make your hierarchy a linear list in your design?

Moreover, if you want complete information for your base classes, you should initialize your base class objects first in your derived class object. Use [C++ initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) to complete this.

```
class Person
{
protected:
    int Id;
    std::string FirstName;
    std::string LastName;

public:
    Person() = default;
    Person(std::string firstName, std::string lastName) : FirstName(firstName), LastName(lastName) {}
    ~Person() = default;
    std::string GetPersonInfo() const;
    std::string GetFirstName() const;
    std::string GetLastName() const;
};

inline std::string Person::GetPersonInfo() const {
    return FirstName + " " + LastName;
}

inline std::string Person::GetFirstName() const {
    return FirstName;
}

inline std::string Person::GetLastName() const {
    return LastName;
}

class Adult : public Person
{
protected:
    std::string Email;
    std::string PhoneNumber;
    std::vector<std::string> Address;
public:
    Adult() = default;
    ~Adult() = default;
    Adult(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber, std::vector<std::string> address) 
        : Person(firstName, lastName), Email(emailAddress), PhoneNumber(phoneNumber), Address(address) {};
    Adult(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber) 
        : Person(firstName, lastName), Email(emailAddress), PhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {};

};


class Teacher : public Adult
{
private:
    int ClassroomID;
public:
    Teacher() = default;
    ~Teacher() = default;
    Teacher(std::string firstName, std::string lastName, std::string emailAddress, std::string phoneNumber,
        std::vector<std::string> teacherAddress, int classroomID) 
        : Adult(firstName, lastName, emailAddress, phoneNumber, teacherAddress), ClassroomID(classroomID) {}

};



int main(void) {

    Teacher teacher("ExampleFirstName", "ExampleLastName", "example@email.com", "100-1001000", {"example address"}, 1);

    cout << teacher.GetLastName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```